# Can someone explain the code to me in Java? How does the % and /= get all the sums of the input?

Tags: java, sum

Can someone explain the code to me in Java? How does the % and /= get all the sums of the input? I am confused about the logic of the code. Thank you.

(Sum the digits in an integer) Write a program that reads an integer between 0 and
1000 and adds all the digits in the integer. For example, if an integer is 932, the
sum of all its digits is 14.
Hint: Use the % operator to extract digits, and use the / operator to remove the
extracted digit. For instance, 932 % 10 = 2 and 932 / 10 = 93.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise_02_06 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     // Create new Scanner object

        // Prompt the user to enter a number between 0 and 1000.
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 1000: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        // Compute the sum of the digits in the integer.
        int lessThan10 = number % 10;       
        number /= 10;                           
        int tens = number % 10;             
        number /= 10;                           
        int hundreds = number % 10;     
        number /= 10;                           
        int sum = hundreds + tens + lessThan10; 

        // Display results
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

% is the remainder operator.  So 14 % 10 is 4.  And with integer arithemtic, the fraction when divided, is dropped.  so 14/10 is 1.

```
So follow this.

total = 0
numb = 932
int n = numb % 10 = 932 % 10 = 2
total = total + n = 2

numb = numb /10 = 93
n =  numb % 10 = 93 % 10 = 3
total = total + n = 2 + 3 = 5

numb = numb / 10 = 9
n = numb % 10 = 9 % 10 = 9
total = total + 9 = 5 + 9 = 14

9 + 3 + 2 = 14
```